# How do I implement a custom formatter for Redis Desktop Manager in Windows?

Tags: python, redis, desktop

Are there instructions for adding a custom formatter to Redis Desktop Manager in Windows?  [Their website here](http://docs.redisdesktop.com/en/latest/native-formatters/) shows how to add custom formatters, but the instructions are for Linux.

I followed these steps based on their instructions:

1. Create directory with meaningful name. Name of the directory will be used as formatter name.
2. Implement a python script that meets protocol described below

   - Note: My python script accepts the command line arguments and outputs a simple "validate", "version", or "decoded" message.  It doesn't support encoding.
3. I included a usage.json file with this content `['python', 'my_super_formatter.py']`

   - Note: That's what's in the instructions.  The single quotes make it invalid json.  I also tried a version of this using double quotes.  The results were the same.
4. I copied my directory to two places.  I figured one of these two paths would be right.

   1. C:\Program Files\RedisDesktopManager\formatters

      - This is the folder path that appears in the Settings window in Redis Desktop Manager
   2. C:\Users<username>.rdm\formatters

      - This is the Windows version of the path specified.

Results:

- No matter what, the list of custom formatters in the Settings window is empty.
- The available formatters in the "View as" dropdown does not include my custom formatter.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I believe you copied the example code from RDM's doc. It's weird though the line with single quotes in the usage.json doesn't work.

By replace the single quotes

```
['python', 'my_super_formatter.py']
```

with double quotes

```
["python", "my_super_formatter.py"]
```

I fixed the problem on my Windows 10.